# What does the 500 internal server error on postman mean?

Tags: node.js, postman

I am very new to postman -
this was my server side code:

```
    var express = require('express')
    var app = express()
    app.use(express.static(__dirname))
    // respond with "hello world" when a GET request is made.
    var messages = [
        {
            name: 'Tim', message: 'Hemlo'},
            {name: 'Jane', message: 'Hoi'
        }
    ]
    app.get('/messages', (req,res)=>{
      res.send(messages)
    })
    app.post('/messages', (req,res)=>{
        console.log(req.body)
        res.sendStatus(200)
      })
    
    app.listen(3008, () =>{
    console.log('server listening') 
    })
```

My post man post call - `localhost:3008/messages`
My Json I wanted to post : `{"name": "jane", "message": "aaa"}`
The output was HTML -

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>ReferenceError: body is not defined<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\malav\OneDrive\Desktop\chatbot\server.js:15:21<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\malav\OneDrive\Desktop\chatbot\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (C:\Users\malav\OneDrive\Desktop\chatbot\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\malav\OneDrive\Desktop\chatbot\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\malav\OneDrive\Desktop\chatbot\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\malav\OneDrive\Desktop\chatbot\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (C:\Users\malav\OneDrive\Desktop\chatbot\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (C:\Users\malav\OneDrive\Desktop\chatbot\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at serveStatic (C:\Users\malav\OneDrive\Desktop\chatbot\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:75:16)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\malav\OneDrive\Desktop\chatbot\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)</pre>
</body>
```

`
I wish to make a post of the data into my app.

Answer (score 1):

The 5xx HTTP errors show an internal error, nothing's wrong with Postman. In case of fix the error, you need to add a JSON parser into your express app instance:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json(/*{limit:'50mb'}*/));
...
```